# Docker build colored messages unreadable

Tags: windows, docker, build

I am using 'docker build' on Windows 10 to build asp net core web app image. However, since the last update, messages are colored in such a way that it gets unreadable. Searching on the internet did not provide any answers.
Any ideas on how to get around this?
[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Updated 2022-08-02]

As of [PR #2954](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/pull/2954) (which may take a bit to get released into Docker Desktop), you can run:

```bash
export NO_COLOR=1
```

There have also been changes to [make the default text colors more readable](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/pull/2368).

---

[Original answer]

With docker, you can pass the `--help` option to a command to see usage. E.g.:

```
$ docker build --help

Usage:  docker build [OPTIONS] PATH | URL | -

Build an image from a Dockerfile

Options:
      --add-host list           Add a custom host-to-IP mapping (host:ip)
      --build-arg list          Set build-time variables
      --cache-from strings      Images to consider as cache sources
      --disable-content-trust   Skip image verification (default true)
  -f, --file string             Name of the Dockerfile (Default is 'PATH/Dockerfile')
      --iidfile string          Write the image ID to the file
      --isolation string        Container isolation technology
      --label list              Set metadata for an image
      --network string          Set the networking mode for the RUN instructions during build (default "default")
      --no-cache                Do not use cache when building the image
  -o, --output stringArray      Output destination (format: type=local,dest=path)
      --platform string         Set platform if server is multi-platform capable
      --progress string         Set type of progress output (auto, plain, tty). Use plain to show container output (default "auto")
      --pull                    Always attempt to pull a newer version of the image
  -q, --quiet                   Suppress the build output and print image ID on success
      --secret stringArray      Secret file to expose to the build (only if BuildKit enabled): id=mysecret,src=/local/secret
      --squash                  Squash newly built layers into a single new layer
      --ssh stringArray         SSH agent socket or keys to expose to the build (only if BuildKit enabled) (format: default|<id>[=<socket>|<key>[,<key>]])                                                                                                                     
  -t, --tag list                Name and optionally a tag in the 'name:tag' format
      --target string           Set the target build stage to build.
```

For turning off the colored output, you can set `--progress plain` which removes the color formatted text and other tty features like updating the time for each build step. You can make this the default with:

```bash
export BUILDKIT_PROGRESS=plain
```

Alternatively, you may just want to change the color of your terminal. Black and white both work nicely. But a bluish background will clash with the blue text.

---

The other option is to disable buildkit and revert back to the classic build engine. That can be done with an environment variable:

```bash
export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0
```

or configuring the default in `/etc/docker/daemon.json`:

```json
{
  "features": {"buildkit": false }
}
```

However, the classic builder will not support features being added to buildkit and is unlikely to see much development going forward.

Comment: Thx a lot, works. I did read the docs but, probably i overlooked this.  Seems to be some secret ....

Comment: I don't have a bluish background on my terminal, but I do have a slightly transparent background, and as a result I find the blue next almost unreadable even when the actual terminal background colour is black. I can do `--progress plain`, but then I'm giving up the other tty features that I like. As well, our build scripts that do a `docker build` are in source control, so to add that switch I have to modify a source controlled file, then make sure I don't commit that change.  I really wish there was just an env var you could set to have the same effect as the switch. :shrug:

Comment: @AdamParkin you could also disable buildkit, but I wouldn't recommend that. I also managed to get buildkit to default back to plain mode by adjusting stdin/stdout/stderr to not be the terminal. Not sure if there's a cleaner way: `docker build . </dev/null 2>&1 | cat`

Comment: Where do I add ```export NO_COLOR=1```?

Answer (score 6):

Just add flag `--progress plain` while running `docker build` command, in the last.

for example,

```sh
docker build -t getting-started . --progress plain
```

Answer (score 6):

Another ev option

```
export BUILDKIT_PROGRESS=plain
```